# Is there a function which swaps two ranges of different sizes within a slice?

Tags: pointers, memory, rust, slice, swap

Swapping ranges of equal sizes can already be done with `std::ptr::swap_nonoverlapping`. But what about ranges of different sizes within a Vec/slice/etc.? Does such a function exist?

For example:

```
let mut vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
function_Im_looking_for(&mut vector, 1..=2, 4..=6);
assert_eq(vector, [1, 5, 6, 7, 4, 2, 3, 8, 9]);
                      _______     ____
```

Comment: Definitely nothing built in for that. What you describe is not actually a "swap" -- the number at index `3` has to be moved into index `4` before the other items can be "swapped".

Comment: That's a bummer. I could implement one myself but it probably wouldn't be the most optimal version. @Herohtar

Comment: [Some quick doodling at the back of an envelop and this seems equivalent to swapping the smallest common range, plus rotating the rest?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07e18f80e6b3edf1d72ff94ed06793c4)